# Import Excel To SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, 32bit-64bit, import-from-excel

Hello everyone I have a little issue which I'm unable to resolve. Here is the context:

I have a 64-bits SQL Server 2014 instance on my computer and a 32-bits Office installation (on which the only component installed is Excel, no Word, no Office Tools, no Office Shared Features...). I try to import some data stored in a .xls file on some network drive on a daily basis, but I'm unable to find the right way to do it. Here's why:

I try this command:

```
INSERT INTO BBImport 
       SELECT * FROM 
       OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=W:\..\aaa.xls;Extended Properties=''''Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes''''')...[Sheet5]
```

After resolving all the permission issues, I finally got this error:

"The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server."

Note: I also tried with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, same error.

I try to install Microsoft ACE 64-bits, but it is not compatible with my 32-bits Office Installation -_-...

---

However I succeed to import the data by using the import wizard of SQL by specifying the followings:

Data Source: Microsoft Excel | Excel Version: Microsoft Excel 97-2003 (or 2007 both worked) | Destination: SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Since that worked, I created a SSIS package for that and import it into my Integration Services Catalog into a new project. But when I try to right-click/Execute, my SQL Server Management Studio stops working and I get those errors in my event viewer:

```
1. Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.ExecuteTask.ShowReport()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
2. Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2014.120.2000.8, time stamp: 0x5306c06d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x8d8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d06c81bcb45ec2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 84f7630f-d87a-11e4-a40a-005056ae5914
 3. Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: ssms.exe
P2: 2014.120.2000.8
P3: 5306c06d
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.0.30319.18063
P6: 526766b5
P7: 170b
P8: 14
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P10: 
Attached files:
These files may be available here:
C:\Users\administrator.CASGRAIN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_ssms.exe_5c1853936685e7ed85eece7cc3339e468fa8b7_0aee4fe2
Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 84f7630f-d87a-11e4-a40a-005056ae5914
```

I Google those errors, but did not find any fix.

And when I try to execute it via a stored procedure by running this code, but nothing happens (no results, no message and my table is still empty).

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'BBImport2.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'test', @project_name=N'BBImport2', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=NULL

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

Do anybody have an idea to help me?

Comment: Have you tried turning off 64bitRuntime within the SSIS package?  Under Project -> Properties -> Debugging.  See linked picture http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/images/dts-to-ssis-package-convert-upgrade-migrate-faq_run_32bit_under_64bit.png

Comment: Install the Access 64-bit run time (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910). This will allow you to use the correct 64-bit `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider in your connections.

Comment: Your SSIS package is returning a "file not found" error.   Try using the correct location of the file you want to import.

Comment: In addition, change your input file to a .csv and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: Tab Aleman - The package successfully import the data when I execute the package immediately with the wizard so the path is good.

Daniel - The file is a file generated by bloomberg and it is made to be used only with that, not even with Excel. However it is possible to extract some data of it and that's what I'm trying to do. If I change the extension of the file, it becomes useless.

gvee - I cannot install the Access 64bit because my Office is 32bits, I got this message "The installation of the package failed" right after executing the .exe and nothing in the event viewer

Comment: TTeeple - I didn't create the package manually with VS. I used the import wizard to create a ssis package of the command and store it as a File system (.dstx). Then, I created a folder in my Integration Services Catalog and Import my package with the Integration Services Project Conversion Wizard and it succeed. Once done, the Integration Services Deployment Wizard starts automatically and I just needed to enter a project name and my project was ready. But now, if I try to validate/execute it, ssms crashes.

Comment: Just to be clearer for the xls file, the file is linked with another system in real-time. When I open the file in excel, the cells contains the formulas to access the data in Bloomberg, so I can't see it from a windows computer. However, the data is available if we use any import command (I get the proper data when I run the package) so it shouldn't be a problem, but I can't rename it or change its extension. But thanks for giving me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue by simply uninstalling Office 32b and installing Office 64b. After a lot of test, the problem was either the compatibility between SQL(64) and Office(32) or the file wasn't fully import since the excel had a lot of vlookup function that search into other sheets and those sheets needed to run the bdp function (Bloomberg function) to be filled.

I successfully run this command to import my xls file:

```
INSERT INTO main SELECT * FROM 
    OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=[path\filename.xls];Extended Properties=EXCEL 8.0')...[tablename]
```

I still can't understand why it was running from the wizard and from VS2013 when I run the package manually, but not when I was importing the package into the SSIS catalog or when I was executing the query directly. It's working now. I guess that it's the only thing that matters...